# I need help merging 2 pieces of code into 1

Tags: javascript, php

I've got 2 pieces of code.

**Nr 1:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', 'add_after_checkout_button' );

function add_after_checkout_button() {

echo '<p class="text-under-place-order">By clicking on the purchase button, you agree to our <a href="https://www.exampledomain.com/terms-of-service/">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="https://www.exampledomain.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></p>';
}
```

and

**Nr 2:**

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5e15d2f246.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        SSL encrypted payment
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <i class="fas fa-undo"></i>
        100% money-back guarantee
    </div>
</div>
```

Code snippet **Nr 1** adds some text in a certain part of my website.

Code snippet **Nr 2** is supposed to be an addition to code snippet **Nr 1** to display some additional stuff above the text.

Can someone please help me merge these 2 pieces of code into 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo out the entire *Nr 2* before or after the checkout button like so:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', 'add_after_checkout_button' );

function add_after_checkout_button() {
echo '<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5e15d2f246.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        SSL encrypted payment
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <i class="fas fa-undo"></i>
        100% money-back guarantee
    </div>
</div>';
echo '<p class="text-under-place-order">By clicking on the purchase button, you agree to our <a href="https://www.exampledomain.com/terms-of-service/">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="https://www.exampledomain.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></p>';
}
```